# How to save ICloudStorageAccessToken?

Tags: c#, save, token, dropbox, sharpbox

I am trying to connect to Dropbox using the Sharpbox library. All the process went fine and I am able to connect, although I don't know how to save the access token for later use from within C#. It cannot be saved into the settings file unfortunately because it is an abstract type. I tried to convert it to string and save it, but I don't know how to convert it back to AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.ICloudStorageAccessToken for future use. So how can I store his token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines at http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/06/unboxing-dropbox-and-sharpbox-2/, I wonder if there's a `CloudStorage.SerializeSecurityToken` (to pair with the `DeserializeSecurityToken` shown in the post).

Comment: Yes, thanks, it helped me to figure out a way to put the SerializedToken into a stream and save it to the file system.